# Prolog exercise that has to connect a conveyor belt to an oven in a factory is not working

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, declarative-programming

I want to create a Prolog program that can connect conveyor belts to ovens and an output belt.
The program has the following facts:

```
factory(12,10).
oven((2,5),(4,5)). 
oven((7,5),(7,5)).
blocked(0,9).
blocked(3,1).
blocked(5,1).
blocked(4,9).
blocked(5,9).
```

Where `factory(X,Y)` gives you the width of the factory (`X`) and the height (`Y`), `oven((X,Y),(OutputX,OutputY))` gives you the x-y coordinates of the bottom leftcorner of the oven (each oven is of size 3 by 3) and their output coordinates (`OutputX, OutputY`), `blocked(X,Y)` represents a square in the factory that cannot contain an oven or a belt.

Then, given the following code `pos_empty(X,Y)` that returns whether a position can have a belt or not, create a term `serveOven(Oven, Length, InBelts, Belts)` that constructs a belt line from each starting belt in the list `InBelts` to the output coordinates of the `Oven` and that line can have a max length of `Length`.
The code to check if a position is empty:

```
pos_empty(X,Y) :-
    \+(blocked(X,Y)),
    \+(has_oven(X,Y)).

has_oven(X,Y) :-
    oven((X1,Y1), _),
    X2 is X1 + 3,
    Y2 is Y1 + 3,
    between(X1, X2, X),
    between(Y1, Y2, Y).
```

The code I got is the following:

```
serveOven( oven(_, (OutX, OutY)), Length, InBelts, Belts) :-
findall(Belt, (member(InBelt, InBelts), make_belt(InBelt, OutX, OutY, Length, Belt)), Belts).

make_belt((X,Y), OutX, OutY, Length, [(X,Y) | Tail]) :-
pos_empty(X,Y),
(X = OutX, Y = OutY;
(X < OutX, NewX is X + 1, make_belt((NewX, Y), OutX, OutY, Length, Tail));
(X > OutX, NewX is X - 1, make_belt((NewX, Y), OutX, OutY, Length, Tail));
(Y < OutY, NewY is Y + 1, make_belt((X, NewY), OutX, OutY, Length, Tail));
(Y > OutY, NewY is Y - 1, make_belt((X, NewY), OutX, OutY, Length, Tail))),
length(Tail, Len),
Len < Length.
```

But this returns nothing. Can anybody help me? Thanks!

So, as said in the details:
The code I got is the following:

```
serveOven( oven(_, (OutX, OutY)), Length, InBelts, Belts) :-
findall(Belt, (member(InBelt, InBelts), make_belt(InBelt, OutX, OutY, Length, Belt)), Belts).

make_belt((X,Y), OutX, OutY, Length, [(X,Y) | Tail]) :-
pos_empty(X,Y),
(X = OutX, Y = OutY;
(X < OutX, NewX is X + 1, make_belt((NewX, Y), OutX, OutY, Length, Tail));
(X > OutX, NewX is X - 1, make_belt((NewX, Y), OutX, OutY, Length, Tail));
(Y < OutY, NewY is Y + 1, make_belt((X, NewY), OutX, OutY, Length, Tail));
(Y > OutY, NewY is Y - 1, make_belt((X, NewY), OutX, OutY, Length, Tail))),
length(Tail, Len),
Len < Length.
```

When running the query `serveOven(oven((2,5),(4,5)), 20, [(11,2)], Belts).` this resulted in an empty list of Belts. Which should not happen.

Comment: You can step through your program, to see exactly what is happening and where it is going wrong, using e.g. `trace.` - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Comment: @brebs, I have been doing that, however, the trace is so long that I keep on getting lost where it is going wrong. I have even simplified the problem by leaving the length constraint out for now. It still does not return anything when it ends.

Comment: So, add e.g. `writeln([X, Y]),` statements at relevant points, to show the variables. There is basically no way that you can state "I wrote this program but I cannot debug it." Just put more effort into debugging it.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, you are right. This should be `oven((2,5), (4,5))`. Thank you for the correction! Also, this should be bottom left, my mistake.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to write `oven((2,5), (4,5))`. What is preventing you from using `oven(2, 5, 4, 5)`?

Comment: @TA_intern, because that is how the facts are given. That is the data that you get, I did not come up with that notation.